# Filesystem watcher to pick and convert XML encoding

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using the filesystem watcher to pick and convert the encoding of a file, the file gets copied at the destination but without conversion. I was using the below code earlier:

```
 string xml = File.ReadAllText(FileName,ansi);
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
             Console.WriteLine("1st");
              File.WriteAllText(
                 FileName,
                  @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" +  xml.ToString(),
                   utf8
               );


             if (File.Exists(destinationFile))
                    File.Delete(destinationFile);
                File.Copy(FileName, destinationFile,true);
                Console.WriteLine("File Copied" + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")); // for troubleshoooting only
                Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit."); 
                Console.Write(CrL);
```

But this is not working now , as the xml file I'm getting now contains the following header:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1256"?>
```

I was earlier suggested the below code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(FileName);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent=true };

 using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationFile))
{
 using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, settings))
 {

    doc.Save(writer);
  }
}
```

But this is not doing the conversion at all. The dest. file is still ansi. It's not doing the conversion to utf8. Am I doing something wrong here

Comment: "The dest. file is still ansi." How do you check it?

Comment: Using notepad or notepad++. It still shows me ansi

Comment: The code (which uses `XmlWriter` class) works just fine: it creates XML-file in UTF-8 encoding with BOM (open the file with any hex editor and you can see the BOM - the first three bytes). Also, notepad++ shows that the file is in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Sergey Brunov : Thanks for checking that. but on my end I'm checking the destination file in notepad++, none of the encoding is ticked in the encoding menu, which means for me it's not utf8. Is there any other way of checking this notepad++. Maybe my way is wrong. Or can I send you the final dest file to check from your side.

Comment: Which version of Notepad++ do you have (I have 6.2.3 at the moment)? You may also try Notepad2 text editor (it shows encoding in status bar of the main window).

Comment: 6.1.2 let me upgrade this and get back to you. thank you.

Comment: @Sergey Brunov : I have upgraded this to 6.3, but this is still the same. In the status window it reads windows-1256, but not utf-8. For notepad2 it's the same. Am I doing something wrong. Is there a possibility to check this if I send you this. I can smell I'm really doing something wrong here but can't figure it out. Maybe it's something with my windows. How can I send you this file ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24497/discussion-between-sergey-brunov-and-user726720)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're rewriting the output file (the file written by `XmlWriter`) with the original one by this code:

```
if (File.Exists(destinationFile))
    File.Delete(destinationFile);
File.Copy(fileName, destinationFile, true);
```

Just remove these lines of code.

## Update

Writing the XML-document using Windows-1256 encoding:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256"),
        Indent = true
    };
```